# how to split all the files in a directory in to 4gb files to a different directory?

Tags: files, clipboard, split

I have a directory containing several large files that are each greater than 4gb.   I want to copy all of those files to a different directory (happens to be a fat32 usb drive mounted), but split the files down to 4gb (since the destination drive is limited to that size files).

I tried this:

```
split -b 4096G /var/lib/backuppc/images/* /usbdrive/
```

but I get a

```
split: extra operand `/var/lib/backuppc/images/xxxxxxxxxmyfilesname.tib'
```

Am I doing something wrong?   (also tried  "4G" instead of 4096G, no difference)

Comment: Did you try with `4G` ?

Comment: yes, just did, no difference

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to first create a tar file:

```
tar -cf /tmp/bigfile.tar /var/lib/backuppc/images/*
```

then split that:

```
cd /usbdrive
split -b 4G /tmp/bigfile.tar
```

If you want to avoid use of the temporary tar file you can pipe tar directly to split:

```
tar -cf - /var/lib/backuppc/images/* | split -b 4G
```

To reconstruct this when you get to the destination, recreate and unarchive the tar file:

```
cat /usbdrive/x* >bigfile.tar
tar -xvf bigfile.tar
```

Again, to do this without the temporary file:

```
cat /usbdrive/x* | tar -xvf -
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` can't take more than one input file as an argument.

You can try using `find` for this

```
cd /var/lib/backuppc/images && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec split -b 4G '{}' "/usbdrive/images/{}" \;
```

Comment: getting there, now getting: /usbdrive/images//var/lib/backuppc/images/Acer_Veriton_X498G_Desktop_Win_7_Pro_OA_FACTORY_BU.tibaa: No such file or directory     (and my /usbdrive/images/ directory does exist)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to take spaces into account, please see the edited command.

Comment: Or, if you don't insist on `split` and preserving permissions etc, use *7z* for example: `7z -v4g -mx0 a /usbdrive/images/images.7z /var/lib/backuppc/images`.