# Use tar to archive automatically file in volumes

Tags: unity, files, filemanager, tar, archive

What is the command to simply archive a file in multiple volumes with tar.
I have a file called `file0`, I want to archive it with tar so that `file0` is split in tar files of let us say 10MB. How can I simply do that ? The GUI of Ubuntu has the option "Split" (for tar) greyed out.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/89284/158442, http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61776/70524

Comment: I cannot do this simple stuff in just ONE command ?

Comment: Why do you need `tar`? If it's just one file, use just ONE command: `split`.

Comment: tar czpf - . | split -d -b 10M - file0 returns "file changed as we read it" and only the first volume is created.

Comment: O.o You're archiving the current directory and saving the archive in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to just tar the file, print the archive to standard output and pass it through split:

```
tar czpf - file0 | split -d -b 10M - file0
```

Note that this isn't quite what you tried. The command you have in [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812451/use-tar-to-archive-automatically-file-in-volumes#comment1228763_812451) (`tar czpf - . | split -d -b 10M - file0`) was using `.` as input. That means that the input "file" for `tar`, the current directory, changed as soon as `split` started writing its output files into the current directory, so `tar` complained. To avoid that, either give `tar` the file name as I did above, or run this from another directory:

```
cd /some/place
tar czpf - /path/to/dir/containing/file0 | split -d -b 10M - file0
```

In both cases, to untar the file, you'll have to cat the files to join them:

```
cat file00* | tar xzvf -
```

Comment: It works but creates a gzip archive. I need tar volumes (and ONLY tar).

Comment: @Henry OK, see update. I used the `z` flag because you did in your comment, so I assumed you wanted it compressed.

Comment: It creates the volumes, the first volume is displayed with the icon of a tar file, but the other volumes have no icon (binary). When I try to extract the files (right click on the first volume) it says: file format not recognized.

Comment: @Henry please edit your question and explain what you need in more detail. For one thing, there's no point in creating a tar of a single file unless you're compressing it. Which means that my answer is kind of pointless without the `z` (as I just realized, so I put it back). I think you're looking for something like the multi-file archives offered by rar. That's not something tar can do. More importantly though, please explain what you're trying to achieve by tarring a single file.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I thought tar could split one file into multiple volumes (not necessarily compressed).